# Counting bigrams without special modules

Tags: python

Recently I have come across a Grok Academy question on Bigrams (two adjacent words).

Considering that Grok asked me to find the bigrams and their frequencies for several lines of input (until nothing is entered), e.g.

```
Line: The big red ball
Line: The big red ball
Line:█
```

The output **should** be `{'the big': 2, 'big red': 2, 'red ball': 2}` because each bigram occurs two times.

My code is shown below:

```
bigrams = []  # setting up variable for all the bigrams
bigram_frequencies = {}  # all the bigrams and their occurences
line = input('Line: ')  # get line input "The big red ball"
while line:  # while something is entered
  line = line.lower()  # convert line to lowercase
  line = line.split()  # ['the', 'big', 'red', 'ball']
  for i in range(0, len(line)-1):
    bigrams.append(line[i] + ' ' + line[i+1])  # getting all the bigrams
  for i in bigrams:
    bigram_frequencies[i] = bigram_frequencies.get(i, 0) + 1  # add 1 if the bigram alredy exists and set to 1 if new
  line = input('Line: ')
print(bigram_frequencies)
```

But the output gives: `{'the big': 3, 'big red': 3, 'red ball': 3}`

Maybe I have gotten the maths wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not cleaning up `bigrams` for each iteration of your `while` loop, so the entries keep accumulating in there.

You don't *need* that variable either, just tally things up into the frequencies array as you're figuring out the bigrams:

```
bigram_frequencies = {}  # all the bigrams and their occurences
while True:
    line = input('Line: ')
    if not line:
        break
    line = line.lower().split()
    for i in range(0, len(line)-1):
        bigram = line[i] + ' ' + line[i + 1]
        bigram_frequencies[bigram] = bigram_frequencies.get(bigram, 0) + 1
print(bigram_frequencies)
```